# Generate random non-repeating integers from a small range

Tags: matlab, random

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I wish to create a vector of integers, from a relatively small range, and ensure that none of the integers will be followed by the same integer.

i.e., This is a "legal" vector:
[ 1 3 4 2 5 3 2 3 5 4 ]

and this is an "illegal" vector (since 5 follows 5):
[ 1 3 4 2 5 5 2 3 5 4 ]

I've experimented with `randi`, and all sorts of variations with `randperm`, and I always get stuck when i try to generate a vector of around 100 elements, from a small range (i.e., integers between 1 and 5).

The function just runs for too long.

Here's one of the attempts that i've made:

```
function result = nonRepeatingRand(top, count)

    result = randi(top, 1, count);

    while any(diff(result) == 0)
         result = randi(top, 1, count);    
    end

end
```

Any and all help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: just a small comment. The condition of non-repeating means that your vector is less "random"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The kind of sequence you are looking for can be defined by generating *differences* from `1` to `top - 1` and then computing the cumulative sum *modulus* `top`, starting from a random initial value:

```
function result = nonRepeatingRand(top, count)

    diff = randi(top - 1, 1, count);
    result = rem(cumsum(diff) + randi(1, 1, count) - 1, top) + 1;

end
```

On my machine, this generates a non-repeating sequence of 10 million numbers out of 1:5 in 0.58 seconds.

Comment: I really can't figure out how you came up with that...? Anyhow, a +1 from me!

Comment: It just occurred to me that the constraint the poster wants to implement is most easily expressed with respect to the diff. So why not generate the diff first and the sequence from that.

Comment: @A.Donda It's wrong! I've called only 5 times the function and I had two sequences with a repeated number.

Comment: @karl71, I tested this extensively, with many very long generated sequences, and there were never any repetitions. Maybe you use "repeated number" in a different way? As explained in the question, this is about *immediate repetitions*, i.e. `2 3 2 1 2` has no "repetitions", but `2 3 1 2 2` has one "repetition".

Comment: @karl71, no worries. :-)

Comment: Btw. if you need "no repetitions at all", have a look at `randperm`.

Comment: whats the point of the randi(1, 1, count) part?  on mine it worked just with rem(cumsum(diff), top) + 1;

Comment: There is some error in the code, for top=2,count=2 it always returns [2,1], never [1,2]. Created a new answer taking this idea, but fixing the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61298461/2732801

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following code for generate Non Repeating Random Numbers from 1 to M

> > randperm(M);

and for K Non Repeating Random Numbers from 1 to M

> > randperm(M, K);

enjoy

Comment: Thanks, but: as you probably have noticed, the question was (very elegantly) answered about a year ago and the correct answer was marked as such. Secondly, i'm afraid you did not answer the question that i asked - if i need a sequence of 100 non-repeating random integers in the range of 1-4, `randperm(4,100)` returns an error of course.

Comment: Your answer is the very simple one, but you are the best dear, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Do not regenerate the sequence every time, but fix the repetitions. E.g.:

```
function result = nonRepeatingRand(top, count)

    result = randi(top, 1, count);

    ind = (diff(result) == 0);
    while any(ind)
        result(ind) = [];
        result(end + 1 : count) = randi(top, 1, count - numel(result));

        ind = (diff(result) == 0);
    end

end
```

On my machine, this generates a non-repeating sequence of 10 million numbers out of 1:5 in 1.6 seconds.

Comment: I think my other answer is better: Faster, and more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the idea from [A. Donda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644302/2732801) but fixing the implementation:

```
r=[randi(top,1,1),randi(top - 1, 1, count-1)];
d=rem(cumsum(r)-1,top)+1;
```

The first element of `r` is a randomly chosen element to start with. The following elements of `r` randomly choose the difference to the previous element, using modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

How this?

```
top = 5;
count = 100;
n1 = nan;
out = [];
for t = 1: count 
    n2 = randi(top);
    while n1 == n2
        n2 = randi(top);
    end
    out = [out, n2];
    n1 = n2;
end
```