# Error while generate non-Repeating Random integer in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I'd like to generate nonRepeating Random integer in matlab.i searched and i saw
[Generate random non-repeating integers from a small range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643799/generate-random-non-repeating-integers-from-a-small-range.But) when i used mentioned code it generate Repetitive number.The code i used was:`nonRepeatingRand2(37,36)`.  my main goal is generate random string from one default string.for example :
my main string is 'abcde' and i want generate 'adbce' from it not 'abade'.
for doing this i am going to generate nonRepeating Random integer and use them as string index , but now because it give me 2 or 3 repetitive  number i have problem.

Comment: are you happy with a xorshift ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

Comment: I would never recommend to implement a random generator on your own, especially if very good libraries are available. It is nearly impossible to notice implementation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a random permutation, thus use `randperm`

```
s='abcde'
s(randperm(numel(s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm for this would be to keep a sorted list of all the integers generated so far.

When you generate a new integer generate it from `min` to `max - numberGeneratedSoFar`.

Then loop through the sorted list, adding one to the generated number for each one you find that is lower until you find the spot in the list to insert it in.

The generated number will be unique and will be completely randomly distributed in the range.

Comment: i am sorry but i have difficulty to understand your explanation. I would appreciate if you could explain with code?

Comment: Sorry, it's a long time since I used matlab. The algorithm will work in anything though.