# Create a matrix of random integers with equal number of occurrences for each integer

Tags: matlab, random, integer

I'm using matlab to create a matrix of random integers 1 to 5 that has each integer an equal amount of times, such that there are an equal number of 4s in the matrix as there are 5s. Weighting the values equally does not work as it still produces unequal occurrences of each number. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can MATLAB produce a random permutation of a given size? In Python+NumPy I'd reduce a permutation modulo 5 (and then add one): `np.random.permutation(20)%5+1` -> `array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3])`

Answer (score 4):

```
numbers = repmat([1:5], 1, 5);
reshape(numbers(randperm(length(numbers))), [5,5])
```

This will create a vector of 1 to 5 and repeat it 5 times, so it's enough for a 5x5 matrix. Can just change 5 to whatever size matrix you need. Then randomly pick through them all to make the vector random. Finally, it is reshaped to a 5x5 matrix.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly. Is it possible to make the random vector have no immediate repeats of integers? So that 1 never follows 1, 2 never follows 2 etc.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885347/shuffle-a-vector-of-repeated-numbers-so-the-numbers-do-not-repeat-in-matlab this link seems to do what you're looking for. You can just make the vector then reshape it as 5x5 to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which generates such a matrix of R rows and C columns. This is not the most efficient code, but it is simple to understand, and has the benefit of working even if equality can't be perfect (i.e if R*C is not a multiple of 5):

```
R = 5;
C = 10;
M = -1 * ones(R, C);
affected = 0;
while affected < R*C
    r = randi([1,R]);
    c = randi([1,C]);
    if M(r, c) == -1
        M(r, c) = 1 + mod(affected, 5); 
        affected = affected + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: if R*C is not a multiple of 5 then by definition you can't have equal quantities of the integers 1 to 5, which is what the OP wants, so the "benefit" is a bit moot...